# Check whether webpage contains infinitive scrolling?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I wanted to know whether there some kind of techniques that would allow to identify infinitive scrolling existence in any webpage?

Answer (score 1):

One generic option would be to actually scroll the page to the bottom `window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)` and then check if the page has grown ([`document.documentElement.scrollHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight)), probably after waiting a couple of seconds.

You could try to improve this approach using a [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but that might also produce more false positives where a change is detected but it has nothing to do with infinite scroll.